# What extension exist for Safari to watch Youtube videos using a foreign IP?

Tags: safari, proxy, safari-extensions

In Germany many (music) videos get blocked on Youtube because Youtube and the [GEMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesellschaft_f%C3%BCr_musikalische_Auff%C3%BChrungs-_und_mechanische_Vervielf%C3%A4ltigungsrechte) have not yet managed to agree on a deal for copyright fees.

This struggle has been going on for years now and there exist plenty of legal solutions for Firefox and Chrome to use a proxy service - provided by an extension - that will enable you to watch the video using a foreign IP (preferably, US or UK).

- Are there extensions for Safari that enable you to watch Youtube videos using a foreign IP?

[image]

Comment: Does http://unblock-us.com work as well for europeans as it does for us westerners?

Comment: @bmike I can't tell, I don't want to try this service if I first have to sign up. However, I've found the following website to be very reliable in providing an alternative for watching Youtube videos: http://www.youtubeunblocker.org/ For the few times where I *need* such help, this is totally enough. :)

Answer (score 2):

this is a common problem, due to possible copyright infringement issues.
you can add the following proxy-url to your bookmarks and use it in combination with copy/paste. sure that is not exactly what you have asked for, but it works and the amount of time is the same!

[01](http://hidemyass.com/) and here is a list of other possible [proxy-hosts](http://www.moreofit.com/similar-to/www.hidemyass.com/Top_10_Sites_Like_Hidemyass/)

Comment: Thanks for links. Unfortunately, the second one is broken and I cannot correct it by changing the URL. Can you please edit your answer and correct it?

Comment: i noticed and already fixed it. i guess i need some sleep.  (:

Answer (score 0):

We go back and forth between America and Britain, and have had to find solutions for similar problems on both sides of the Atlantic. Here in the UK I've had success with a VPN service called [VPNOD](http://vpnod.com/). It isn't a Safari extension, but it's easy to switch on and off when you need it.

VPNOD has excellent [setup instructions online](http://vpnod.com/setup/osx/). Once you've configured the VPN, you can go to System Preferences > Network, select your VPNOD connection, and check the box that says "Show VPN status in menu bar".

From then on you can activate your VPN by choosing "Connect VPNOD" from the menu bar. Once the connection is active, you should be able to see YouTube as an American would.

Answer (score -3):

this is a common problem, due to possible copyright infringement issues. you can add the following proxy-url to your bookmarks and use it in combination with copy/paste.

Comment: which proxy-url?

Answer (score -4):

youtube has blocked so many videos but youtube unblocker automatically adds a link to play the blocked videos as it opens in a new tab via proxy site and the video will be submitted and can start playing the video.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the software mentioned?

Comment: Yeah, a link would be really helpful. From what I found, this extension is developed by [Lunaweb](http://www.lunaweb.de/), a German company. But I cannot find an official download link.